# iPhone 4 would not turn on unless it is plugged in

Tags: iphone

So my phone would only turn on when it's plugged in and I just bought it yesterday so I'm kind of frustrated because I don't know what do about it.

Comment: -1 for proofreading the title.  If you just bought it, take it back.

Comment: Assuming that you actually mean an iPhone 4 then you must have bought it used, and it must be quite old, so the battery is probably shot.

Answer (score 2):

Your battery is mostly likely dead and needs replacing. You have three options:

1. Take to an AppleStore (expensive - and probably not cost effective as you have bought the phone second hand);
2. Purchase a replacement battery and [replace it yourself](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+4+Battery+Replacement/3141)
   (Luckily, replacing the battery on the iPhone 4 requires minimal
   disassembly), or;
3. Send it to a battery replacement service (easily found online, or
   offered through eBay, and not too pricey)

This has happened to me many times (5 or 6 times) and I always go for option three, because I am lazy.

Comment: and another + for today :), all this for correcting my spelling, thanks!